# How to I return JSON in flask python fetched from another url to the browser?

Tags: python, flask

I want to use flask to return JSON to the brower with or without simplejson (with appropriate headers) here is what I have so far for my flask application:

```
@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    QUERY_URL="http://someappserver:9902/myjsonservlet"
    result = simplejson.load(urllib.urlopen(QUERY_URL))
    return result;
```

Assuming the JSON output returned is:

```
{"myapplication":{"system_memory":21026160640.0,"percent_memory":0.34,
"total_queue_memory":4744,"consumers":1,"messages_unacknowledged":0,
"total_messages":0,"connections":1}
```

When I visit the page `http://localhost:5000` however, I get a `Internal Server Error`. What must I do with "result" to get it to display appropriately? Or is there some way I can tell it to return with `json` headers?

When I add a print statement to print the result I can see the JSON, but in the browser it gives me an `Internal Server Error`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
import requests
r = requests.get(QUERY_URL)
return r.json

#normal return
return jsonify(username=g.user.username,
               email=g.user.email,
               id=g.user.id)
```

jsonify is available in flask. Here is the [docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.json.jsonify)